# Comma in front date_field in Rails (Windows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am having this weird comma in front of my rails site

[image: Comma in front of date_field]

I checked with some friends and they don't have this problem when using the site. I'm using Rails (Windows/Chrome) with Bootstrap

Below is the code and generated html

```
<%= f.date_field :dob %>
<input type="text" name="..." id="...">
```

Comment: Can you paste the full .erb view?

Comment: Are you using pure bootstrap? Or you're using plugins, themes, etc?

Comment: I am using this gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.6'